# Update className with UseEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently i am practising my React skills. Now i am working on my Hooks knowledge. I have used a Coctail API to load some data. Just for fun i divided this up into three categories with a navigation bar.

When i click on the navigation items i go to the subcategories. But my classes won't update so the tab system doesn't work. You guys know what i have to do here? I tried this in a few different ways but none worked.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const OverView = () => {
  const [ term, setTerm ] = useState('Gin');
  const [ categorie, setCategorie ] = useState('Cocktail');
  const [ debouncedTerm, setDebouncedTerm ] = useState(term);
  const [ results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedTerm(term);
    }, 10);

    return () =>{
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [term]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const search = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios({
        'method':'GET',
        'url':'https://the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com/filter.php',
        'headers':{
          'content-type':'application/octet-stream',
          'x-rapidapi-host':'the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key':'49adf3a5ccmsh5d525b0005370d3p1b460bjsn7b0add17579e',
          'useQueryString':true
        },'params':{
          'i': debouncedTerm
        },
    });
    setResults(data.drinks);

    };
    search();
  }, [debouncedTerm]);

   const renderResults = results.map((result) => {
    return (
      <div key={result.idDrink} className="four wide column" style={{marginBottom:"20px"}}>
        <a href={result.idDrink}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={result.strDrinkThumb} width="250"/>
            <div className="header">{result.strDrink}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="ui grid">
      <div className="row">
          <h3>Select your favourate drink to get started</h3>
          <div className="ui top attached tabular menu">
            <div
              className={'item active'}
              onClick={(e) => setTerm('Gin') }>
              Gin
            </div>
            <div
              className={'item'}
              onClick={(e) => setTerm('Vodka')}>
              Vodka
            </div>
            <div
              className={'item'}
              onClick={(e) => setTerm('Whiskey')}>
              Whiskey
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div className="row">
          {renderResults}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OverView;
```

Thanks in advance.My first problem is that i don't know how to add an extra action upon my hook. I can't attach an extra onClick event and don't know how to add this to my useEfect functions.

Comment: There's no code to update any `className`s in your example.

Comment: Yes i removed it, beceause it was to confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `className` based on the `term` state atom, simple as that.

I also refactored things a bit:

- the result component is now, well, a separate component
- searching is refactored into a separate function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ResultCard = ({ result }) => (
  <div className="four wide column" style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
    <a href={result.idDrink}>
      <div className="card">
        <img src={result.strDrinkThumb} width="250" />
        <div className="header">{result.strDrink}</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
);

async function doSearch(term) {
  const { data } = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com/filter.php",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "the-cocktail-db.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "49adf3a5ccmsh5d525b0005370d3p1b460bjsn7b0add17579e",
      useQueryString: true,
    },
    params: {
      i: term,
    },
  });
  return data;
}

const OverView = () => {
  const terms = ["Gin", "Vodka", "Whiskey"];
  const [term, setTerm] = useState("Gin");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    doSearch(term).then((data) => setResults(data.drinks));
  }, [term]);

  return (
    <div className="ui grid">
      <div className="row">
        <h3>Select your favourate drink to get started</h3>
        <div className="ui top attached tabular menu">
          {terms.map((t) => (
            <div
              className={["item", term === t ? "active" : null].filter(Boolean).join(" ")}
              onClick={(e) => setTerm(t)}
            >
              {t}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        {results.map((result) => (
          <ResultCard result={result} key={result.idDrink} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OverView;
```

You may want to look into the [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) module; the arcane `[].filter().join()` expression would become `cx({item: true, active: t === term})` :)